# Scriptable application that can handle SMS/MMS

Tags: sms, applescript

I am making a program in AppleScript that uses texting correspondence.  Up until now, I have used IFTTT (in which the script emails IFTTT and IFTTT texts the person or visa versa), but  it glitches a lot and can only text one person. Does anyone know of a scriptable (controllable by applescript) application that can text? Thanks. Also, I'm sort of a novice with AppleScript, so please don't use any fancy lingo in your answers.

Comment: It seems a weird idea to use AppleScript for such a non-platform-specific thing, but maybe this is just part of what you're planning. In any event, if I were you I'd look into using Safari or Chrome, somewhat AppleScript-friendly apps (as opposed to Firefox which is not AS-friendly enough), and whatever Google released as an API for docs: this, perhaps: http://developers.google.com/google-apps/documents-list/?csw=1#what_can_this_api_do

Comment: @CRGreen Do you have an idea for another language to use? I am familiar with AppleScript, but am open to learning a new language. I was going to use it because, If a scriptable application existed, I could control it with AppleScript. But maybe I could still handle SMS with [Twilio](https://www.twilio.com/) or something similar to that.